# vector pointer in struct can't convert vector in main what is wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

trying to get the pointer to point to my vector in main

```
struct mystruct
{
    vector<string> *data;
};

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec;
    mystruct s;
    s.data = vec;
}
```

By doing it this way i get "`error: cannot convert std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > to std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > in initialization`"

what have i done wrong?

Comment: `vec` is not a pointer.

Comment: You either copied the error message wrong or your compiler is bad. It is supposed to say something like [this](https://ideone.com/h70ht5); "cannot convert from `vector` to `vector *`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign a non-pointer to a pointer variable (except for literal zero). What you want to do is to set the value of the pointer to be the address of the variable. To get the address, you can use the address-of operator:

```
s.data = &vec;
```

The type of the address-of expression will be a pointer to the type of the argument expression.

Answer (score 2):

> what have i done wrong?

You assigned a non-pointer variable to a pointer variable. A pointer can be assigned:

- another pointer variable.
- an address of a variable.
- 0, NULL or nullptr.

**`vec` is non of the above. You need to use `&vec` instead.**

Consider this:

```
    string s = "string"; 
    string *p = &s;  // correct. a pointer is assigned an address.
    //string *p = s; // wrong. assigned a non-pointer variable.
    string *v = p; // correct. a pointer assigned to another pointer.
```